# Got rejected at tech company twice, do big tech companies have a limit on number of times you can apply?

Tags: interviewing, tech-industry, reinterviewing

I'm a grad student majoring in Computer Science. I interviewed with a big 4 tech company last year for an internship position, but didn't do well. I got the rejection after a day. I was blessed to have an opportunity this year, and I did pretty well. Unfortunately, I got a rejection after about a week and 3 days (I think I may have been their second choice). My question is simple: do big 4s and other tech companies in general have a cap on the number of times you can apply with them? Also, to generalize, do tech companies have a cap on the number of times you can apply with them?

Comment: I'm sorry, don't quite understand what you mean by that.

Comment: That's a question for Microsoft.

Comment: This is company specific so of little use to other people who access the site, voting to close as off topic

Comment: Please ask a recruiter or HR representative for Microsoft. Google and LinkedIn (acquired by Microsoft) will have you wait 6 months before you can reapply.

Comment: @jcmack so there's no cap on the number right? Just the fact that you have to wait before reapplying? Microsoft has a 1 year wait period, but my question is basically does Microsoft have a cap on the number of times you can apply.

Comment: @VilasSanchez Not sure about Microsoft, but Google definitely doesn't. I'd be surprised if a software company has a cap on number of times you can apply.

Comment: I needed four attempts to be hired at my current employer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Each company will have different policies; but any competent one will have a record of people who have interviewed with them in the past and very likely the reasons for any rejection. That's not to say you won't get another chance in due course, but on a subsequent application you will need to convince the initial contact that you've dealt with those reasons, eg. you've developed your skillset in such a way that it's worth reconsidering you, or you've switched to a different role.

If you just keep applying with nothing new to offer each time, then eventually they will likely lose patience and just automatically ignore you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Microsoft or any other company has that kind of policy, but it seems like a dumb one to have, and i really don't think a policy like that is something generalized. You will learn from courses and from experience, perhaps you don't fit now but no one can say you won't in the future. So, don't worry too much about that, keep studying, try to work somewhere else to get experience and apply again in the future.